# How to use IF(LEN in a LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a join based on an IF statement with multiple conditions and a LEN and am not able to get it to work.

```
SELECT
    "Datafeed-WO"."Billing Cd" AS 'Billing Type',        
    IF(LEN("Datafeed-WO"."Zip")  = 6, 'CDA', 'USA') AS 'Country',
    "BudgetTbl"."BudYr" AS 'Budget Yr',
    "BudgetTbl"."Budget" AS 'Group Budget'

FROM "Datafeed-WO"

LEFT JOIN "BudgetTbl" 
   ON ( IF(LEN("Datafeed-WO"."Zip")  = 6, 'CDA', 'USA') = "BudgetTbl"."Country")  
      AND  ("Datafeed-WO"."Billing Cd"  = "BudgetTbl"."Billing Cd")
```

Thanks for any help getting this resolved!

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN "BudgetTbl" 
   ON ( IF(LEN("Datafeed-WO"."Zip")  = 6, 'CDA', 'USA') = "BudgetTbl"."Country") ` This doesnt look good. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: first of all change double quotes `"`to backticks `\`` surrounded table names and column names like `\`Datafeed-WO\`.\`Billing Cd\``

Answer (score 0):

You need to change all those quotation marks (' and ") to backticks (`) and try to execute it again.
Henceforth, it is also important not to include spaces in table and column names.

Hope this is what you intended to have:

```
select
    dw.`Billing Cd` as `Billing_Type`,       
    if(len(dw.`Zip`)  = 6, 'CDA', 'USA') as `Country`,
    bt.`BudYr` as `Budget_Yr`,
    bt.`Budget` as `Group_Budget`
from `Datafeed-WO` dw
left join `BudgetTbl` bt on (dw.`Billing Cd` = bt.`Billing Cd`) and ((len(dw.`Zip`) = 6 && bt.`Country` = 'CDA') || (len(dw.`Zip`) != 6 && bt.`Country` = 'USA'));
```